# Play different animation on every other rollover?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a couple of buttons which have corresponding movieclips. Every movieclip has two different animations (first starts at frame 1, second on frame 20). 
I want the animations to play alternating on `MOUSE.OVER`

Now I am wondering how to do this with one function. Buttons are always named e.g `thing` and movieclips `thing_mc`.

I was thinking something like this:

```
var thing_bo:Boolean = false;

function over(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var mcName = e.currentTarget.name + "_mc";
    var yourContainer:DisplayObjectContainer = e.currentTarget.parent as DisplayObjectContainer;
    var mc = yourContainer.getChildByName( mcName );

    var boName = e.currentTarget.name + "_bo";

    if (!this['boName']) {
        mc.gotoAndPlay(1);
        this['boName'] = true; 
    } else {
        mc.gotoAndPlay(20);
        this['boName'] = false; 
    }
}
```

How to I get this to work? Is there a simpler way?

EDIT: I think the problem is simply accessing the Boolean. The change isn't happening on `thing_bo`.

Comment: first, your if condition will ALWAYS be true.  Second, please clarify where the code you've shown resides in relation to your buttons.  Are all your buttons instances of the same movie clip?

Comment: why will it always be true? the thing with the buttons and movieclips works fine, just the alternating thing not.

Comment: it will always be false actually.   because your `boName` will always have a value.  You didn't answer my questions...

Answer (score 1):

Like @VasilGerginski said, is better to create a `Class` to achieve that, but if you want to do it in a frame here you have a possible code (you could store a variable inside a `MovieClip` object):

> This example assumes that all your instances are in the same scope.

```
var cant:uint = 4;

var i;
var button:InteractiveObject;

for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++){

    button = this.getChildByName("m" + i) as InteractiveObject;

    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollButton);

}

function rollButton(evt:MouseEvent):void{

    var movie:MovieClip = (evt.currentTarget.parent as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildByName(evt.currentTarget.name + "_mc") as MovieClip;

    movie.gotoAndPlay( (movie.boo) ? 20 : 1 );

    movie.boo = !movie.boo;

}
```

[Download example](http://xprimiendo.com/examples/FLASH/buttons.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a class for example MenuItem for each pair of button/animation you have that will hold a reference to the button, the animation it triggers and in a boolean a flag property. This saves time querying for each element every time. :) OOP my friend